# Use a loop to create multiple objects with mongoengine / pymongo in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I am trying to create multiple objects from a json-api response.

```
for team in resp.json():
    t = Team(key=team['Key'], name=team['FullName'], bye_week=team['ByeWeek'], logo_url=team['WikipediaLogoUrl'])
    t.save()
```

The problem is, this only ever saves one object at a time. For instance, I have defined the document so that each can only have a unique `key=...` field, and if it already exists, to skip it. Each time I run the script, it creates only the next item.

```
from mongoengine import Document, StringField, IntField, DateTimeField
from uuid import uuid4
from datetime import datetime


class Team(Document):
    _id = StringField(primary_key=True, required=True, max_length=50, default=str(uuid4()))
    key = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    name = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    bye_week = IntField(required=True)
    logo_url = StringField(required=True)
    created = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.utcnow())
    last_modified = DateTimeField(required=True, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

How can I loop over and save each object? I read something about mongoengine being async in javascript, but I'm not sure if that applies to python.

Comment: In PyMongo you can use `collection.insertMany` to make a single call to the database. `insertMany` takes a list of dictionaries as argument.

Comment: I wanted to use mongoengine because I define documents. Do you know if this has a similar feature?

Comment: I believe there is such feature. Search for this: _"mongoengine insert multiple documents"_.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem was being caused because I tried to define a custom `_id` option using UUID4. My best guess is that the way mongoengine handles UUID does not assign the value correctly, so each time, it creates one UUID, not one UUID per object; then, as the list cycles, it is updating that existing id and not creating a new one.

Comment: This is why it works on subsequent program runs, but only for one more object than the last time, because a new UUID is generated per program run.